# How do I create a ManyToManyField relation in Django that involves two fields?

Tags: python, django

My simplified models:

```
class Weapon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want it so that I can define a different Weapon field **price** and it will be different from each City. I tried adding the following to the Weapon class:

```
price = models.ManyToManyFields('City')
```

..but it only gives me a list of which sort of answers: "This weapon is available in which cities?" rather than "What are the different prices for this weapon in each city?"

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [intermediary model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) on the ManyToMany field:

```
class Weapon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField('City', through='Vendor')

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')
    weapon = models.ForeignKey('Weapon')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [`ManyToManyField (through=...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

You can create your many to many table explicitly with a foreign key to each of the other models.  I think that is what you are after